# update multichoice column using powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, multiple-values

how do can we update multichoice column using powershell csom ?

we need to update multichoice column for a list

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You update it with an array:

```
$listItem["multichoicecolumn"]="Choice 1","Choice 2","Choice 3"
$listItem.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script by [pnp PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)(SharePoint 2013).

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url http://sp
$options = "A", "B"
Set-PnPListItem -List MyList -Identity 1 -Values @{"MultiChoice" = $options}
Write-Host 'done'
```

Comment: Nice, I also prefer PnP, but the OP asked for CSOM :)